# UITableView isn't displaying data

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

AppDelegate

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    UIStoryboard *myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainSB" bundle:nil];
    tCont = [myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Table"];
}

- (void)serviceAdded:(NSNetService *)service moreComing:(BOOL)more {
    tCont.server = _server;
    [tCont addService:service moreComing:more];
}
```

TableController

```
- (void)addService:(NSNetService *)service moreComing:(BOOL)more {
    [self.services addObject:service];
    if(!more) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

`server` is correctly carried over, and `service` is added to `services`. But I don't see it in my table view. Is it because I'm trying to instantiate the view before it exists?

**Update:** I've done a little more debugging and found that TableController is initialized before my delegate calls for it. I've only seen one TableController thread, so my code is most likely the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an `UIWindow`, set its `rootViewController` property to your table view controller and send it the `makeKeyAndVisible` message. You also have to implement the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method on your table view controller.